# How many layers will be used in ASP.net application?

Tags: asp.net

I have migrated one asp application into the ASP.Net application, in asp.net application I have created the design pages dynamically from .aspx.cs file. Now i want know How many layers are used in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a simple ASP.NET application without and business layer or even database or accessing other external resources, you have a single layer application.  Add a database and you have to two layer.  Business logic layer would be the third